# Java web start won't launch

Tags: java, web, java-web-start

I made a Java web start programme and it worked fine on my computer but when I try to deploy it on another computer the Java web start doesn't launch.

When I check the task manager I found that javaws.exe starts and exits after a second or two.

The computer is 64 bit and there are two java environments installed: JDK 1.6 64bit and JRE 7 32bit

When I try to open it from the command prompt it works fine.

I think its caused by a conflict between the JREs.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**edit** : 
here is the code  **ctjnlp.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file; charset=ISO-8859-1"   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="${urljar}" href="${actionName}?id=${guid}">
 <information>
    <title>Creative Scanner</title>
    <vendor>Creative Technologie</vendor>
 </information>
 <security>
 <all-permissions/>
 </security>
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"  java-vm-args="-Xms256M -Xmx1024M" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="false"/>

<jar href="lib/ctScan-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/httpclient-4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/httpcore-4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/httpmime-4.2.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/icepdf-core-4.2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/icepdf-viewer-4.2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-awt-util-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-dom-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svggen-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-util-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-xml-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/device-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jericho-html-3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-imageio-core-standalone-1.2-pre-dr-b04-2011-07-04.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core-1.1.3.jar"/>

 </resources>
 <application-desc name="Creative Scanner" main-class="ma.creative.ctScan.CreativeNumerisation">
 <argument>${guid}</argument>
 <argument>${urljar}</argument>
 <argument>${scancompletpage}</argument>
 <argument>${scanuploadpage}</argument>
 <argument>${destinationfolder}</argument>
 </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

here is the code of the **generated jnlp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:9090/archives/" href="jnlp.action?id=c576a5cb-e758-4aeb-9bb3-7fa70cf7d5ca">
 <information>
    <title>Creative Scanner</title>
    <vendor>Creative Technologie</vendor>
 </information>
 <security>
 <all-permissions/>
 </security>
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.5+"  java-vm-args="-Xms256M -Xmx1024M" />
    <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="false"/>

<jar href="lib/ctScan-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/httpclient-4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/httpcore-4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/httpmime-4.2.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/icepdf-core-4.2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/icepdf-viewer-4.2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-awt-util-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-dom-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svggen-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-util-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-xml-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/device-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jericho-html-3.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/itextpdf-0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jai-imageio-core-standalone-1.2-pre-dr-b04-2011-07-04.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core-1.1.3.jar"/>

 </resources>
 <application-desc name="Creative Scanner" main-class="ma.creative.ctScan.CreativeNumerisation">
 <argument>c576a5cb-e758-4aeb-9bb3-7fa70cf7d5ca</argument>
 <argument>http://localhost:9090/archives/</argument>
 <argument>scanComplet.jsp</argument>
 <argument>scanUpload.action</argument>
 <argument>scannerData</argument>
 </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: I assume that your problem is in JNLP descriptor. Can you post it?

Comment: @AlexR i edited the post to see the hole code